# Why is Style ignored in my custom Echo error function?

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, customization, style, message-coding

To highlight the type of error that occurred the function `echoError` (via `err`) should display type of error in color: `Red` for "Error" or `Yellow` for "Failed" but that is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong?

```
Options[echoError] = { fail -> False};
echoError[fname_, arg_, details_ : "", comment_ : "", 
   OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{
    err = 
     If[OptionValue@fail, Style["Failed!", Yellow], 
      Style["Error!", Red]],
    com = If[StringLength@comment > 0, " " <> comment, ""] 
    },
   Echo[ToString@Style[Evaluate@err, Red] <> " " <> details, 
     ToString@fname <> " arg: " <> ToString@arg <> ToString@com <> 
      "   \[Rule] "]
    ;];
arg = "value of arg";
echoError["fname", arg, "details", "(comment)", fail -> False]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style the prompt as well. The main point is that text is styled, not a string. Also, yellow is not very visible on a white background.

```
Options[echoError] = {fail -> False};
echoError[fname_, arg_, details_String : "", comment_ : "", 
   OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{
    err = If[OptionValue@fail, "Failed!", "Error!"],
    com = If[StringLength@comment > 0, " " <> comment, ""],
    prompt = 
     ToString@fname <> " arg: " <> ToString@arg <> ToString@com <> 
      "   \[Rule] ",
    msg = ""
    },
   msg = ToString[Evaluate@err] <> " " <> details;
   Echo[If[err == "Failed!", Style[msg, Red, 12], 
     Style[msg, Yellow, 12]], prompt];
   ];

arg = "value of arg";
echoError["fname", arg, "details", "(comment)", fail -> False]
```